# Does Jodatime have a method to get the months and days since some older date?

Tags: java, jodatime

I would like to know exactly how many months and days(possibly years) some older date is from today. Is there a method to do that?

I know how to get the difference of the months, I know how to get the difference in days. But I am unable to get the months and the days.

Ex:

old = '2013-03-04'
now = '2013-04-17'

so the result im looking for is something like 1 month(s) and 13* day(s)

*maybe its 12 im not every sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by using [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) in JodaTime.

For example,

```
LocalDate old = new LocalDate(2013, 3, 4);
LocalDate now = new LocalDate(2013, 4, 17);

Period p = new Period(old, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

To get the months, use `p.getMonths()`, to get the days `p.getDays()`.

The result of the example is 1 month, 13 days.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [the documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Intervals) of intervals:

> **Intervals**
>
> An interval in Joda-Time represents an interval of time from one
>   instant to another instant. Both instants are fully specified instants
>   in the datetime continuum, complete with time zone.
>
> Intervals are implemented as half-open, which is to say that the start
>   instant is inclusive but the end instant is exclusive. The end is
>   always greater than or equal to the start. Both end-points are
>   restricted to having the same chronology and the same time zone.
>
> Two implementations are provided, Interval and MutableInterval, both
>   are specializations of ReadableInterval.