# Difference between two Date

Tags: java, date

I want to find difference between 2 Date in months and days using Java. For example: difference between **5/16/2013** and **7/20/2013** is **2 months and 4 days**.

Thank you for your consideration on this matter.

Comment: The short answer is use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) - it deals with things like leap years, seconds and all that fun stuff

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16067960/1288408) for a solution using Joda Time.

Answer (score 7):

Use joda time library as its better to handle dates http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Something like this `Days.daysBetween(first DateTime, second DateTime).getDays();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
     java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date date1 = df.parse("2012-09-30 15:26:14+00");
    java.util.Date date2 = df.parse("2012-08-30 15:26:14+00");
    int diff = getMonthDifference(date1, date2);
    System.out.println(diff);


    public static int getMonthDifference(java.util.Date date1, java.util.Date date2) {
        if (date1.after(date2)) {
            return getMonthDifference0(date1, date2);
        } else if (date2.after(date1)) {
            return -getMonthDifference0(date2, date1);
        }
        return 0;
    }

private static int getMonthDifference0(java.util.Date date1, java.util.Date date2) {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(date1);
        c2.setTime(date2);
        int diff = 0;
        while (c2.getTimeInMillis() < c1.getTimeInMillis()) {
            c2.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            diff++;
        }
        int dd = c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (dd > 0) {
            diff--;
        } else if (dd == 0) {
            int hd = c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if (hd > 0) {
                diff++;
            } else if (hd == 0) {
                long t1 = c1.getTimeInMillis() % (60 * 1000);
                long t2 = c2.getTimeInMillis() % (60 * 1000);
                if (t2 > t1) {
                    diff--;
                }
            }
        }
        return diff;
    }
```

Comment: I've used this approach in the past and though it was good but it has a problem when dealing with DST and Standard dates e.g. Try getting the number of days between 2013-03-09 and 2013-03-12 on GMT -6.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
    Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 0, 1);
    Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 2);
    int monthDiff = (c2.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c1.get(Calendar.YEAR)) * 12 + c2.get(Calendar.MONTH) - c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dayDiff;
    if (c1.get(Calendar.DATE) < c2.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
        monthDiff--;
        dayDiff = c1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - c1.get(Calendar.DATE) + c2.get(Calendar.DATE); 
    } else {
        dayDiff = c2.get(Calendar.DATE) - c1.get(Calendar.DATE);
    }
    System.out.println(monthDiff + " " + dayDiff);
```

Comment: Over short distances and same time zones, this is okay, but it begins to suffer when you expand the range and start dealing with things like leap years and seconds, century cross overs just to mention a few

Answer (score 0):

Nobody said console.log( new Date("2013-09-30") - new Date("2012-01-01") ); It will give you difference in milliseconds. Its up to you to handle time zones and so forth when creating those 2 objects.